# What's the right way to template static front-end .js files inside the "public" folder (using Express/NodeJS and EJS)?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Is there a way to "template" static front-end .js files (the ones inside the "public" folder) the same way I'm templating my HTML with EJS?

Is that even possible? If yes, what's the best way to do it?

Comment: Why would you template a JS file?  What problem are you trying to solve?  We could help you better if we knew what you were actually trying to accomplish rather than just asking a non-specific question about a technology.

Comment: two issues
1- trying to get some variables from the mongoDB database
2- I'm creating a French version of the website, need to translate about a hundred error messages in French for the French version

Comment: Get some variables from the mongoDB database to do what with them?  Please be a lot more specific with your actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @jfriend00  to use them in the front-end javascript code;  My question: what is the easiest way to bring back-end variables to front-end?

Comment: Whan you serve the page on the back-end, insert data into Javascript variables in the HTML page.  Then, your client-side Javascript can access those variables in the page and have access to that data that came from the back-end.  The other way to do things is that your front-end Javascript makes Ajax calls to the back-end to retrieve the data that it needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templating js, css files is really a bad idea because browsers cache those js files if they have **Cache-Control** headers and most of the reverse proxies like cloudflare sets the Cache-Control headers by default to all static files.

There are two ways you can solve this problem.

1. Using the hidden form fields

EJS:

`<input type="hidden" name="language" id="language" value="<%-language%>">`

JS:

`var language = document.getElementById('language').value;
console.log(language)`

2. Simply write a script block in your ejs file before you add your .js files and assign the variable values there.

EJS:

`<script> var language = <%-language%></script>`

JS:

`console.log(language)`